# Sharing code between static methods

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to share code between Javascript static methods, without making the shared method public?

For example:

```
// public method
Company.getByUri = function(uri)
{
  // ...
  return gotCompany(data);
}

// public method
Company.getByName = function(name)
{
  // ...
  return gotCompany(data);
}

// Should be a private method, but I'm forced to keep it public
Company.gotCompany = function(data)
{
  // ...
  return new Company(data.name, data.creationDate);
}
```

Comment: What makes `Company.gotCompany` private?

Comment: @elclanrs: right now, nothing. I'm asking how I can make it private and still invoke it from the two public methods.

Comment: Don't think about private or public or static in the broader sense, because it doesn't translate well. All we have is closures. What you can do is wrap everything in an IIFE and export a facade for your API.

Comment: @elclanrs: please post an answer with a code sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use closures:

```
var Company = (function() {
    function Company(a, b) { /* ... */ }
    Company.getByUri = function(uri) {  return gotCompany(data); }
    Company.getByName = function(name) {  return gotCompany(data); }
    function gotCompany(data) {
        return new Company(data.name, data.creationDate);
    }
    return Company;
})();
// Here `Company.getByUri` and `Company.getByName` are available,
// but not `gotCompany`
```